# ...a note from the Eurasia Group, a consultancy. - how to understand the last part "a consultancy"?

Tags: grammar

Source: http://www.businessinsider.com/russia-scores-massive-gas-pipeline-deal-with-china-2014-5

> The deal between Russia's Gazprom and China's state-owned energy giant CNPC was confirmed by sources in the Russian energy sector, according to a note from the Eurasia Group, a consultancy.

They first say **a note from the Eurasia Group** and then add a comma and the words **a consultancy**. How should I understand that last part - **a consultancy**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple appositive explaining who the Eurasia Group is-- a consultancy.

Comment: Or you could say"...Eurasia Group, which is a consultancy."